# Does the double integral $\int_1^\infty \int_0^x \frac{1}{x^3+y^3} \,dy \,dx$ converge or diverge?

Tags: calculus, integration, convergence-divergence, polar-coordinates

I would need to determine whether the following double integral converges or diverges:
$$\int_1^\infty \int_0^x \frac{1}{x^3+y^3}\, dy\, dx$$

I made a change of variable to polar coordinates and therefore I got:
$$\int_0^\frac{\pi}{4} \int_1^\infty \frac{r}{r^3\cos^3(\theta)+r^3\sin^3(\theta)} \,dr \,d\theta$$

Which simplifies to:
$$\int_0^\frac{\pi}{4} \frac{1}{\cos^3(\theta)+\sin^3(\theta)} d\theta$$

I can't get any further from here. I cannot evaluate this integral by hand and I don't know what I should do next. Is this approach correct in this problem?
Thanks!

Comment: Try to evaluate it. You’ll find the convergence along the way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another solution using no fancy change of variables. Just note that $\frac{1}{x^3+y^3}\leq \frac{1}{x^3}$ for $y\geq 0$ and thus,

$$
\int_1^{\infty} \int_0^x \frac{1}{x^3+y^3}\textrm{d}y\textrm{d}x\leq \int_1^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^2}\textrm{d}x<\infty
$$

Comment: Nice direct approach (+1)

Answer (score 2):

Your approach is fine, but not the best one. Hint for the last part: show that for $\theta\in [0,\pi/4]$,
$$f(\theta)=\underbrace{\cos^3(\theta)}_{>0}+\underbrace{\sin^3(\theta)}_{\geq 0}$$
is positive and continuous. What may we conclude?

By the way, your integral in polar coordinates is GREATER than the given one
(which is OK in order to prove convergence):
$$\int_0^\frac{\pi}{4} \int_1^\infty \frac{r}{r^3\cos^3(\theta)+r^3\sin^3(\theta)} dr d\theta=\iint_D\frac{1}{x^3+y^3} dy dx> \int_1^\infty \int_0^x \frac{1}{x^3+y^3} dy dx$$
where $D=\{(x,y): x^2+y^2\geq 1,0\leq y\leq x\}\supset
\{(x,y): x\geq 1,0\leq y\leq x\}$.

Comment: Okay, thanks! I've been thinking for a little while now and I'm not really sure what we could conclude from that?

Comment: @LocationUnknown Is the integral of $1/f$ finite over $[0,\pi/4]$? You are integrating a positive and continuous function on a compact interval!

Comment: Oh yeah, of course! Thanks!! I got the intuition behind the idea! I think I can finish the problem from here!

Comment: @LocationUnknown Well done! Please see my edit.

Answer (score 2):

The polar coordinates bounds are incorrect. It should really be

$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\int_{\sec\theta}^\infty \frac{1}{r^2(\cos^3\theta+\sin^3\theta)}dr\:d\theta = \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\frac{\cos\theta}{\cos^3\theta+\sin^3\theta}\:d\theta$$

$$=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\frac{\sec^2\theta}{1+\tan^3\theta}\:d\theta = \int_0^1\frac{1}{1+t^3}\:dt = \frac{\log 2}{3}+\frac{\pi}{3\sqrt{3}}$$

from partial fraction decomposition.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that if you use polar coordinates your region actually simplifies to the following:
$$I=\int_1^\infty\int_0^x\frac{1}{x^3+y^3}dydx=\int_1^\infty\int_{\pi/2-\arctan(x)}^{\pi/2}\frac{rdrd\theta}{r^3\cos^3\theta+r^3\sin^3\theta}$$
However as you may notice it is difficult to get rid of this term involving $x$.

Comment: A change of variables should never have any of the starting variables left over in the new expression.

Comment: I know- I was trying to demonstrate what the actual limits should look like but it is hard to convert

Comment: I have the real limits on my answer if you want to take a look. Conversion is easier if you look at a picture. The lines $y=x$ and $y=0$ are all lines of constant $\theta$. Then all that is left is to look at the line $x=1$

Comment: Good answer, did you change order of integration first? How did you work these out

Comment: From my previous comment, it was a picture. Plus, these are extremely common polar coordinates bounds.

Comment: I tried to draw out the region myself and struggled to get it- fair play

Comment: Does the logic I wrote out make sense though? Do you understand this step: "The lines $y=x$ and $y=0$ are lines of constant $\theta$." ?

Comment: Yes I'll take another look and see if I can get it :)

Comment: Right I think I got it- drew a triangle where hypotenuse is r adjacent is 1 and the opposite would be tan(theta)